What movie has a man drowning a little girl in a nightgown in a river?
I am trying to identify a movie clip I saw as a child. I literally know nothing else about the film. It was made BEFORE 2000 and what I recall a man drowns a little girl in a river by submerging her and then bringing her back up again before submerging her again. I THINK she was in a nightgown, and I am 90% sure she was a child. It was a river or a stream or something. It didn't seem like an old film at the time, I'd say it was made between 1979-2000.
I frequently have bad dreams about this scene and would like to go and watch the film so maybe I can put it in context instead of on loop in my head. I know it is not River's Edge, Mermaids, or Don't look now.

Cabin by the Lake (2000)?

Sure it was a movie?  It couldn't be music-video or something?

There is a similar scene of a drowning in the movie Minority Report. Unfortunately, it came out in 2002 so the time-frame is wrong.

I know you said it's from before 2000, but I'm thinking of the movie [link url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0161081/"]What lies beneath[/link] with Harrison Ford and Michelle Pfeiffer, which is from 2000 exactly. Any chance this could be it?

Are you sure this is a drowning and not an immersion baptism? If you were a small child when you saw it, you may not have understood what you were seeing.

The only movie I can think of that involves a man drowning girls in any body of water is Cabin By The Lake (2000), but I'm pretty sure none of his victims are children. They are all teenagers or young women.


very creepy plot. Does he watch them drown or something?

@MathewFoscarini, Not quite, he kidnaps them, dresses them up in nice clothes (mostly dresses/gowns) and then ties blocks to feet and tosses them in the lake. Then he comes back later to tend to them like a "garden" (he actually refers to them as his garden). The movie used to come on USA Network a lot, and has a sequal.

There is at least one scene, I believe where the girl is trying to get away and he keeps having to push her back under the water to try and drown her.

omg that is creepy.

Ive seen that. Not the movie. This scene was a man physically forcing a girl under the water, not tying them to something heavy and tossing them in a lake.

I think you might be referring to K-PAX which came out in 2001, but if I recall the film correctly the main character thinks he's an alien when in fact he killed his family. If my memory is correct he drowns them in the river (including his daughter).
So he creates this alternate identity to deal with what he did.
EDIT: I haven't watched that film in a while. The family might have been murdered or something like that.

Thank you for trying to help but that's not the movie. It was made too recently. The movie i'm looking for is at least before 2000. I am fairly certain before 1998. I only know this because at the time my father was married to wife number 2 and I saw this clip at her home. in 2000/2001 he was already divorced and we lived with my grandmother. So it needs to be date specific to a degree

Nice suggestion. You have a typo in the spelling of the title though. It's K-PAX (instead of the X you put a K). Also, It's not really confirmed if he's an alien or not. Personally, I (and others) think he was in fact an alien inhabiting a humans body.

let me go back just a little further than 1998... could it be 1931's Frankenstein? The title character's trouble began when a girl drowned:


Maybe if there was a remastered version. The clip was in color. I'll have to look into that.

Who knows it's a remake of this movie you're looking for?
